# Number of orbits of coloring of an $n$-gon

Tags: group-theory

Assume that I have an $n$-gon in the plane. Say $S$ is the set of all colorings of vertices of the $n$-gon with $m$-colors (two vertices may have the same color). What is the number of orbits of the action of $D_{2n}$ on $S$?

I believe that it should not be very hard to compute it using Orbit-Stabilizer theorem however there are so many terms and I am highly confused with all the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Burnside's lemma, this is $\frac{1}{2n}\left(\left(\sum_{d|n}\phi(\frac{n}{d})\cdot m^d\right) + n\cdot m^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\right)$ when $n$ is odd. Here, $\phi(n)$ denotes the Euler totient function.

The terms relate to the symmetries of the $n$-gon. For each $d|n$, there are $\phi(n/d)$ rotations of order $n/d$ in $D_{2n}$; each one fixes those elements of $S$ whose colouring repeats every $d$ vertices. There are also $n$ reflections; each fixes those elements of $S$ whose colouring is symmetric about the vertex on the reflection axis.

When $n$ is even, the expression is slightly different: $\frac{1}{2n}\left(\left(\sum_{d|n}\phi(\frac{n}{d})\cdot m^d\right) + \frac{n}{2}\cdot m^{\frac{n}{2}} + \frac{n}{2}\cdot m^{\frac{n}{2}+1}\right)$

The difference is because the reflection axes of an even-sided regular polygon are of two types: those passing through two vertices, and those bisecting two edges.